# Has anyone gotten Playwright installed and running on Windows Server?

Tags: .net, windows-server, playwright

I built a tool using Playwright dotnet, and it runs great locally. I'm trying to deploy it on my Windows server so other people can use it, and the problem is getting the headless browsers properly installed on the server.

If I do all of the quickstart tasks on https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro within Windows PowerShell out on the server, it goes fine until the `playwright install` step. At that point I get the following Error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0...

Even if I try inputting the command `dotnet add package System.Runtime` it adds the package, but then when I try `playwright install` again, it throws the same error.

I even went so far as to try deploying the app anyway, and when I get to the part that requires Playwright, it says:

> `Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated.` 
> `Please run the following command to download new browsers:`
>
> `npx playwright install`

*(PS, it's stupid that the validator insists the above error is code and won't let me submit unless this is formatted this way)*

So I said screw it and installed Node on the server, then ran the npx command, and it says it installed the browsers, but I still get the same error telling me to run the npx command.

Has anyone had any luck getting Playwright installed and implemented on a Windows server?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to first run `dotnet build` in the test project. Then `playwright install`. And then `dotnet test`

Comment: That's what I had tried as well as part of the process of going through the quickstart tasks. Unfortunately (I even tried it one more time just to be sure), I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I built a small console application using Playwright. When trying to run the published console application from another machine (other than my development PC), I was getting the error:

```
Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     playwright install                                                  ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team
```

After running `playwright install` I was getting the error:
`Couldn't find project using Playwright.`

What I did was copy over the project solution folder to my other machine, ensure in your terminal that you `cd` to the folder that contains the `.sln` file, playwright then picked up the `playwright install` cmd and installed the browsers required. I was then able to execute my console application.

Comment: Hmm, seem to be getting the same error. Good idea, regardless.

Comment: "ensure in your terminal that you cd to the folder that contains the .sln file" I think that you should cd to the folder contains the .csproj file.